# should I git rebase twice?

Tags: git

I have the following situation with a repo.

Over the master branch I made a branch "MyAwesomeFeature" and made several commits.

Later the remote master moved so I `git pull origin master` and later rebased my branch to the top of master. No problem there

I wanted to try an experiment in my branch, so I did `git checkout -b MyExperiment` over MyAwesomeFeature branch.

Now master has moved again.

So my question is

1. How can I rebase *both* branches and keep the structure?  (in the past when I rebased the tip, that was the branch rebased but the other stayed )
2. Is there a way that I can rebranch "MyAwesomeFeature" over master and then create *another* branch over master with *only the changes* of MyExperiment?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Git 2.38.0, you would rebase only the "longest" branch and use [`--update-refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---update-refs):

```
git switch MyExperiment
git rebase -i --update-refs origin/master
```

This will update `MyAwesomeFeature` for you.

Before Git 2.38 you can choose different approaches. Rebase twice:

```
git rebase origin/master MyAwesomeFeature
git rebase --onto MyAwesomeFeature MyAwesomeFeature@{1} MyExperiment
```

Rebase once, but reseat the updated branch manually:

```
git rebase origin/master MyExperiment
git log origin/master..   # look up the new commit that MyAwesomeFeature should point to
git branch -f MyAwesomeFeature <that_commit>
```